# Javascript await result

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

i have here a simple code but at the moment i dont find the right way how to code it, can you tell me how i must code it that the function ReadCheck() give me the result from server and not just "undefined"

```
function Check()
{
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var data = { nuser: "username", nemail: "email", };
            
            xhttp.open("POST", "api/posts/check", true); 
            xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
            if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
             {
                return this.responseText;
             }
            }
            xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(data));
}



function ReadCheck()
{
     console.log(Check());
}
```

Comment: `Check` doesn't return anything to be logged inside `ReadCheck`.

Comment: Please read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send). You probably want to send and also use `onload` to trigger whatever functionality you want when the request has resolved. Your current function does not return anything (because your `if` condition is initially `false`). Which means it returns undefined. You probably want to return a promise resolving when the request has resolved.

Comment: Call Check() and change `return this.responseText;` to whatever you need to do to process the response

Comment: You might find [this](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/n98tjohy/) useful.

Comment: Also read the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/send-post-data-using-xmlhttprequest). Both methods work (`onreadystatechange` and `onload`).

Comment: You might find this useful.  => that was usefull, thanks